# Regular Expression for comma separated numbers with possible n spaces following each comma

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking for the above

1,2,3 is allowed
1, ____2_____,3_____, is allowed where _ is space
1 **_ 2 _** 3 is not allowed  where _ is space

Thanks

Comment: please provide few allowed and not allowed strings

Comment: What have you tried? You will probably get a warning shortly, that there has to have been some attempt at this, that we can advise on. Start by playing with regex on an interactive site, perhaps https://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `^ *\d+ *(?:, *\d+ *)*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SiHl6f/1)

Answer (score 1):

i use `*` to match 0 or more occurences of space and `+` for 1 or more digit and finally i use [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match spaces and comma without capturing them

```js
const str = "1,    2,   3   ,  4,5,6   ,";
console.log(str.match(/[0-9]+(?= *,)/g));
```

When i thought about your problem again i came to conclusion that doing whole thing with just regex but not be the simplest approach

```js
const str = "1,    2,   3   ,  4,5,6   ,";
console.log(str.split(",").map(element => element.match(/[0-9]+/g)).filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: This nearly works, what about the case of a single number say 3 this failes

Comment: You should provide more example strings that pass and not pass the match. A single number 3 should pass the test even if there are no commas? if so, what would happen if i had "1_3" does it count as a single number 3 at the end? should it pass?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this one: `/^([0-9]+\s*,\s*|[0-9])+/`

`[0-9]+\s*,\s*` is there to detect numbers followed by comma and `[0-9]` for the last number in the list.